# emberjs form submission in modal window

Tags: forms, ember.js, modal-dialog

Looking over this example:  http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/

Everything works fine to open/close the modal, but **form submission does not work**.

For example, take the modified jsbin example:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qoyuyalifu/1/

I have an action on submit in the form tag, yet clicking Submit does not submit the form.  In other words, it doesn't seem to be recognizing the action on the form tag.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expecting the `sendForm` action to fire but you don't declare it anywhere.

Have a look at his JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ruqikokoti/1/edit

I added the `sendForm` action in ModalController